# Struct in obj c defined in one class interface is not available to other classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, structure

I have defined a structure in one class interface.
I have used it in that class properly. But I m not able to refer to this structure in other classes.
I think I m missing some basics. Generally struct data type defined in one class should be accessible to all the classes in the project right? Why is this not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Where to define macros to be avaivable everywhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769959/objective-c-where-to-define-macros-to-be-avaivable-everywhere)

Answer (score 2):

If the struct is declared in your class .h file, you have to import the .h file wherever you need to access the struct.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any other way that does not need importing the file?

Comment: You can declare it in a completely separate file, if you don't want to import the class header, and import this file everywhere you need the struct.

Answer (score 1):

If you have definitions that need to be shared amongst several modules then it's best to place them in a separate, common header file and import that header file wherever needed. This design is clean and highly extensible.

Comment: How does this behave in other languages like c. There also do we need importing the file where struct is defined?

Comment: It behaves the same way in C. And by the way, Objective C is just an extension/superset of C.